# Make an NN utilize other NNs as part of its decision process

Tags: neural-networks, sequence-modeling, model-request, feature-extraction

Suppose I have a NN that learns to predict the time it takes a robot to move between two jobs. That's three inputs (for starters): robot, job A, job B. Not all robots travel at the same speed, and jobs are not symmetrically spaced.

Suppose I have another NN that learns how long a robot takes to do some given job. All robots can do all jobs, but the robots are not equally effective at all jobs.

Now suppose that I want to make some new NN that takes a list of robots and a list of jobs and gives me robot-to-job map and sequence that minimizes the time to accomplish all jobs. **Conceptually, how can I make this third NN utilize the knowledge contained in the other two NNs?** What do you call this type of architecture? What structural form for this third NN do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow models can be their own layers as part of a larger architecture.
(If you want to see an example you can check out a notebook I have [here](https://github.com/delta2echo/tensorflow_portfolio/blob/main/04_Transfer_Learning/04_Transfer_Learning_Project.ipynb) and [here](https://github.com/delta2echo/StackOverflow_Responses/blob/main/Multivariate_LSTM.ipynb))

Specifically what you are trying to do is called [**transfer learning**](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/transfer/what_is_transfer_learning)
but in general, a NN model can take *any* numerical input set and use it to output another numerical output set. The input can even be the outputs of other models, and their hidden layers.

Suppose you have 2 models each with 4 layers, that take 2 datasets X1 & X2 and output 2 other sets:<br

> X1 -> M1(L1,L2,L3,L4) -> Y1
> X2 -> M2(L1,L2,L3,L4) -> Y2

You can directly [concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) the outputs (Y's) of each model into a *new input* to a 3rd model:

> [Y1, Y2] = X3 -> M3(L1,...) -> Y3

*or*
you can slice each model and at one of the hidden layers and feed **those** outputs to M3:

> [M1L3, M2L3] = X3 -> M3(L1,...) -> Y3

You can even mix and match in any way you find that works:

> [M1L3, M2L2, Y1, Y2] = X3 -> M3(...) -> Y3

If you use a TensorFlow model, 'layers' is a property of the [**model**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#attributes_1) and you can slice them as needed to build [custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers).

However, if you just want to feed the outputs of each model [Y1,Y2] to M3,
I would probably do this using tensorflow's functional api creating two branches:

```
Input1 = tf.keras.Layers.Input(...)
Input2 = tf.keras.Layers.Input(...)
x1 = M1(Input1)   #pretrained model 1
x2 = M2(Input2)   #pretrained model 2
Output = M3(x1)
Output = M3(x2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[Input1,Input2],
                       outputs=[Output]
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How do I tell TensorFlow to not update the borrowed models when training the conglomerate?

Comment: to prevent layers from being trained you can explicitly set a 'trainable' [parameter](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning) for the models .